# How do global structs work?

Tags: solidity

How do global structs work? (That are outside of specific contract) How are they deployed when used in different smart contracts?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global structs work by allowing them to become public and any contract that imports the .sol file that contains the global structs can use them. In other words, declaring a struct outside a contract allows it to be shared by multiple contracts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure "Global Structs" is a thing, but perhaps de facto standard lingo for an approach to structure and inheritance.

It's common to define "types" as `structs` in `interfaces` or `libraries` and then inherit those `.sol` files in multiple contracts. In that way, declare-once/use-many and avoid repetition.

For example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.16;

// Interfaces are useful for describing contract "types" and can contain data types as structs.

interface IMyContract {

    struct Foo {
        uint x;
        address[] instances;
    }

    function doSomething(uint a) external;
}

// use import { IMyContract } from "./IMyContract.sol" to break this into separate files.

// "is" means:
// "does" understand struct Foo
// "must" implement doSomething()

contract MyContract is IMyContract {

    Foo foo; // instance of Foo

    // implementation of doSomething()
    function doSomething(uint a) external {
        // carry on
    }
}
```

You can also declare `structs` in libraries with functions that work with those "types". This can be very useful. In this contrived example, the entire application state is placed inside a `struct` in a library. Using storage pointers, a small pointer to storage is passed around (32 bytes) but the library gets the *whole* state of the application, so it can proceed with complex data manipulation operations.

```
library AppLib {

    struct AppData {
        address[] foo;
        mapping(address => Bar) bars;
    }

    struct Bar {
        uint a;
        address b;
        mapping(uint => address[]) somethingArrays;
    }

    function storeSomething(
        AppData storage self,
        address foo_,
        address bar_,
        uint a_,
        address b_,
        uint index_,
        address[] calldata somethingAddresses_
    ) internal {
        self.foo.push(foo_);
        Bar storage bar = self.bars[bar_];
        bar.a = a_;
        bar.b = b_;
        bar.somethingArrays[index_] = somethingAddresses_;
    }
}

contract App {

    using AppLib for AppLib.AppData;

    AppLib.AppData app;

    function write(
        address foo_,
        address bar_,
        uint a_,
        address b_,
        uint index_,
        address[] calldata somethingAddresses_        
    ) external {
        app.storeSomething(
            foo_,
            bar_,
            a_,
            b_,
            index_,
            somethingAddresses_
        );
    }
}
```

Those patterns might give you some ideas about structuring your code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Import solidity file to use global structs that are declared `public` in other contracts deploy them first, you can use the structs that are declared outside contract as global struct in other solidity file or you can use `Library` in solidity. Check - https://solidity-by-example.org/library/